# ARM Illegal instructions/access violations in Windows CE threading (C++)

Tags: multithreading, windows-ce, wxwidgets

I have a program which contains a thread implemented as a derived class of wxThread. Sometimes this program crashes with either illegal instructions or access violations but always somewhere in the code executed by the thread.

I have even tried to remove the thread and replace it with a trivial Win32 thread that looks like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI LoggerThread::winthread(void* arg) {
  while (true) { Sleep(2000); }
}
```

And it still crashes with an access violation on the Sleep(2000) line intermittently, but almost always after around 30 seconds.

Most recently, it crashes with illegal instructions (more specifically, undefined instructions), on a static function which the wxThread class calls:

```
void* LoggerThread::Entry() {
while(true) {
    if (queue->size() > 0) {

        SOCKET sd = LoggerThread::Init(); /* Crash on this line */ 
            /* ....... */
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the console is the following:

> Undefined Instruction: Thread=8e823ac4 Proc=8c329400 'Opcode.exe'
>   Undefined Instruction: Thread=8c69663c Proc=8c329400 'Opcode.exe'
>
> AKY=00004001 PC=800003f8(???+0x800003f8) RA=006492bc(Opcode.exe+0x006392bc) BVA=05ffed24 >FSR=000000f5
>
> AKY=00004001 PC=003ade44(Opcode.exe+0x0039de44) RA=004cc784(Opcode.exe+0x004bc784) >BVA=05ffed24 FSR=000000f5
>
> Data Abort: Thread=8e823ac4 Proc=8c329400 'Opcode.exe'
>
> AKY=00004001 PC=80188d03(NK.EXE+0x00008d03) RA=80000059(???+0x80000059) BVA=1e07807b >FSR=000000f3
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x003ade44 in Opcode.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.
>
> The thread 'public: static unsigned long __cdecl wxThreadInternal::WinThreadStart(void *)' >(0x2fb5e2c6) has exited with code -1073741795 (0xc000001d).
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x80188d02 in Opcode.exe: 0x80000002: Datatype misalignment.

The project is VC++ (Visual Studio 2005), and I have also tried compiling with the Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK, the Standard SDK, and the Pocket PC 2003 SDK. I have been testing my code on the MC55 and the MC3090, both do the same, but I think perhaps the MC55 is quicker to crash.

It is worthy to note that if I compile my source as a Win32 program (it is wxWidgets based) it works without any issues.

Could anyone give me an idea of where I could look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about wxWidgets, but I'd probably start by looking at this definition:

```
DWORD WINAPI LoggerThread::winthread(void*)
```

According to your console output, wxThreadInternal::WinThreadStart is

[__cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zkwh89ks%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

What calling convention does WINAPI specify on ARM? Maybe WINAPI specifies

[__stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zxk0tw93%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)?

Sorry for the funky formatting :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. WINAPI seems to specify __stdcall, should I be considering using __cdecl or another convention? The TTY sample from the SDK doesn't explicitly give one - DWORD PortReadThread(LPVOID lpvoid)

Comment: @Alwyn -- I think paulcam is likely onto something here -- we had a similar issue in a Win CE application which turned out to be exactly this, i.e. specifying the wrong calling convention for a function passed as a parameter to an API method. Using the wrong calling convention is definitely wrong, it can stuff up the stack. Fix it anyway and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I sorta cut my own answer short. The high order bit around calling conventions is that they have to line up with what's expected. You might take a few minutes to read up on them [in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), and then read up a bit on the specifics for [Windows compilers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58(v=VS.80).aspx). As @AAT mentioned, it might be easier to just specify the calling convention that wxWidget expects to see if it works. Other approaches would include looking at the code after preprocessing, and looking at the ASM in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses - great ideas. I've read the links you sent me, and I have also read that CreateThread() expects __stdcall, so I have adjusted it to reflect that. Unfortunately this hasn't solved the problem, but I am starting to think it has something to do with wxWidgets, since the problem does not occur if the main wxFrame is not created. The moment the wxFrame is created (no controls at all, just the window), it starts crashing again. I have gone down this road before, but I guess I wasn't patient enough to observe whether or not it was indeed crashing. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry -- I don't know anything about wxWidget :(

Comment: No problem, I'm still hunting the bug and will post here when I find it. Thanks anyway for your suggestions - they will most certainly come in handy at a later stage!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! It turned out that wxWidgets is not compatible with the Standard SDK. I switched over to Windows Mobile SDK 5.0 before to check but there happened to be another runtime issue that stopped that build from working as expected. Advice I have to others is make sure you do NOT use the Standard SDK for your WinCE app with wxWidgets. It may appear to work at first, but you will eventually fall into this trap like I did... Thanks all

Comment: Also something that might help are the following in setup.h of WinCE wxWidgets build:`
#define wxUSE_EXCEPTIONS    1    
#define wxUSE_DEBUGREPORT 1   
#define wxUSE_STACKWALKER 0   
#define wxUSE_ON_FATAL_EXCEPTION 0   
#define wxUSE_DEBUG_NEW_ALWAYS 1   `
Also, I originally compiled the code without exceptions enabled in wxWidgets, even though I used exceptions in my code.